# Chrome extension to blur whole page except for circle where pointer is

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create a chrome extension that works similar to this, where everything is blurred except for a circle around the mouse pointer -> http://jsfiddle.net/Zword/XS93A/ :
[image: effect I'm trying to create from jsfiddle referenced above]

I've been trying to use without jquery but with no luck

My problem: the jsfiddle example is very heavy on jquery methods and seemingly only works over the one image. I would like to understand how I can recreate the effect over a whole web page without jquery

Result so far:
[image]

My code:

**content.js**

```
var body = document.body;
body.classList.add("body");
var cursor = document.createElement("div");
cursor.setAttribute("id", "cursor");


if (document.title.indexOf("Google") != -1) {
    body.appendChild(cursor);
    cursor.classList.add("cursor");
    body.classList.add("enableBlur");
    cursor.classList.add("disableBlur");
  
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
        var y = e.clientY;
        var x = e.clientX;
        
        var cursor_y = cursor.style.top = y + "px";
        var cursor_x = cursor.style.left = x + "px";
        
    });
}
```

**background.css**

```
.body>* {
    filter: blur(5px);
}

.disableBlur {
    filter: blur(0px);
}

.cursor {
    position: absolute; 
    width: 100px; 
    height: 100px; 
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    transition: 0.001s; 
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
    border-radius: 50%; 
    pointer-events: none;
    border: 2px solid #000; 
    z-index: 999;
    filter: blur(0px) !important;
    
}
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "name": "Blur",
    "description": "Blurs everything except pointer",
    "version": "0.1",
    "permissions": [
        "tabs","<all_urls>"
    ],
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "images/get_started16.png"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
        "matches": [
            "http://*/*",
            "https://*/*"
            ],
        "js": ["content.js"],
        "css": ["background.css"],
        "run_at": "document_end"  
        }
    ], 
    "manifest_version": 2
}
```

Comment: So , Can you explain the problem you are facing ?

Comment: Use CSS masks to exclude the circle.

Comment: @theFrontEndDev To clarify, I'm having problems understanding how I can use the approach on the jsfiddle given, which uses jquery and only deblurs an image, and applying a similar concept to a whole web page without jquery

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks for the tip, will investigate